# How do you get a list of pages a user has created and how do you post to a particular page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am obviously missing something here.  I can successfully login to FB and can access all of the user data.  However I see no references on how to work with the users pages that they have created and then allow them to post to the pages.

I am wanting to allow the user to choose which of his pages he wants to post to and then post to them.

So here is what I am dealing with in the code, I am successfully logged on and can post to my wall.  Here is the code I am using at that point to get the list of

```
 NSArray *pagePermissionsNeeded = @[@"manage_pages"];


[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/accounts"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error){
                              NSDictionary *currentPermissions= [(NSArray *)[result data] objectAtIndex:0];
                              NSMutableArray *requestPermissions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[]];


                              for (NSString *permission in pagePermissionsNeeded){
                                  if (![currentPermissions objectForKey:permission]){
                                      [requestPermissions addObject:permission];
                                  }
                              }


                              if ([requestPermissions count] > 0){

                                  [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:requestPermissions
                                                                        defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                                          if (!error) {

                                                                              [self functiontoListPages];
                                                                          } else {

                                                                              NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                                                          }
                                                                      }];
                              } else {

                                  [self functiontoListPages];
                              }

                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                          }
                      }];
```

I used the code from th Facebook samples as my starting point and a trying to figure it out.  I still have yet to be able to find anything outside of FB to give samples or tutorials.

Comment: The Pages API documentation explains both of these concepts; how to get permission from a user to manage their pages, and how to use the API to update the page - is there something specific you're having trouble with?

Comment: I have read through that and am still not getting what needs to be done.  From what I can gather is that once the user is successfully logged on I will need to get a lit of their pages and the page tokens.  From there I will be able to post to whichever page they want to post to.  However they do not go over or explain how to get the page names or tokens. (At least not in a way I comprehend)

Comment: Correct - that's exactly it - you'll need to understand how getting permission from a user works and how access tokens work to understand how to make the API calls for page management - 
I recommend starting here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

This document is the most detailed explanation of the access token and permissions models but may need you to read the overview first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: I have read through all of those and have even yanked snipets of code from their examples and torn it apart.  I am still no closer to getting the pages information.  I can get the user tokens all day.  I can get good logins.  None of this gets me any closer to the pages nor does the docs help

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather the `manage_pages` permission in the OAuth process to be able to do this. Then, you can get the Page Access Tokens by requesting

```
/me/accounts
```

for the relevant user. See docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-pages

Comment: While this is correct it still doesn't get me any closer to a solution

Comment: Well, why not? I don't really understand.  Every page is the User administers is listed by this call, including the Page Access Token.

Comment: I don't see where you handle the result of the request. Where's the functiontoListPages?